# Multiple AES Key Derivation from a master key

Tags: encryption, hash, aes, key-derivation, hkdf

I need cryptography advice regarding this [issue](https://github.com/Soluto/kamus/issues/375).

Kamus is a service that encrypts secrets for applications running on Kubernetes. When using AES (actually, Rijndael) symmetric encryption, Kamus uses a single key to encrypt the secrets for all apps.

Let's say I want to create from the generic key, a key that is unique per application - so that secrets that are encrypted for a specific application will not be able to decrypt with the key of another application (this is the case when using a KMS). I'm looking for an algorithm to "derive" a key from the application name (the service account name, to be accurate), something like:

`f(key, name) = key`

Is there an algorithm that I can use? What is the best approach here?

Comment: HKDF(key + name, digest_len)

Comment: @SamG101 HKDF not defined as you listed. If we combine extract and expand then HKDF(IKM , Salt, info, length)

Comment: Ohh right yes you're right, I was just suggesting the concept

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Multiple Key Generation from a Master key**

HMAC-based Key Derivation Function (HKDF) [rfc5869](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869) is what you are looking for. [HMAC security proof](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Emihir/papers/hmac-new.pdf) uses the fact that the compression function of the underlying hash is itself a PRF.

> HKDF follows the "extract-then-expand" paradigm, where the KDF
> logically consists of two modules.  The first stage takes the input
> keying material and "extracts" from it a fixed-length pseudorandom
> key K.  The second stage "expands" the key K into several additional
> pseudorandom keys (the output of the KDF).

**Extract**:

$$\text{HKDF-Extract}(salt, IKM) \to PRK,$$where  $PRK$ is a pseudorandom key.

**If the Input Key Material (IKM) is already a random key, as in your case, then the extract is not necessary, Expand is enough**. HKDF can be used without the salt, however, using salt adds to the strengthening of HKDF and supporting **source-independent** extraction. Two different salts with the same $IKM$ result in fundamentally two different $PRK$s. And, in general, $x$ different salts with the same $IKM$ result in fundamentally $x$ different $PRK$s.

**Expand**:

$$\text{KDF-Expand}(PRK, info, L) \to OKM,$$where OKM is Output Keying Material. L is the desired key length.

The info can be used for the application-specific tag to derive different keys.

$$\text{KDF-Expand}(\text{Inittal Key}, \text{"application 1"}, 128) \to OKM_1$$
$$\text{KDF-Expand}(\text{Inittal Key}, \text{"application 2"}, 256) \to OKM_2$$

---

**What is the probability of generating the same key, i.e. collision**

It is hard to talk about directly on the HKDF, however, if we model it as a  uniform random function $f$, where $f(x)$ is uniform random HKDF value for each combined input ( $x = salt || IKM $) then we can turn back to birthday collisions.

Let $P(C; n, k)$ denotes the usual collision probability among $n$ people with $k$ possible birthdays. And, the usual way is to calculate from the complement $P(D; n, k) = 1 - P(C; n, k)$, that is all birthdays are distinct. Then we can approximate by

\begin{equation}
  P(C; n, k) = 1 - P(D; n, k) \leq \frac{n^2}{k}.
\end{equation} where $n \leq k/2$. The detail is [everyhwere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack), and therefore skipped.

We have two cases;

1. The collision on the generating the $x$s. You may consider this as salt collision too if IKM is set fixed. For $n$ inputs $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ the collision probability is $P(C; n, k)$. When this occurs, that is the conditional probability than the outputs $f(x_1),f(x_2), \ldots, f(x_n)$ will have a collision with probaility 1.
2. If the inputs $x_i$s are distinct then this has $P(D; n, k) = 1 - P(C; n, k)$ probability. Now, conditionally on this we can have collision on the outputs $f(x_1),f(x_2), \ldots, f(x_n)$ with $P(C; n, k)$ probability.

Now sum up the above, then we have;

$$P(C; n, k) + (1 - P(C; n, k)) \cdot P(C; n, k) \\ = 2 P(C; n, k) - P(C; n, k)^2 \leq 2 \frac{n^2}{k}$$

So, this is just double of the usual collision attack. If you are not going to generate $2^{64}$ keys for a 128-bit key it then is not a problem for you. This case may be a problem with the multi-target attack. This is why you need to use AES-256.

You may notice that $2^{64}$ with 128 makes 2, this is due to the fact that the probability bound is not good for $n \approx \sqrt{k}$, there are tighter bound however when the input passes $\sqrt{k}$ it fastly approaches to 1.

It is important to note that 50% probability is too high in the sense of the adversary. One should stop way earlier than this. If you use AES-256, you should use it ( or ChaCha20 that has a 256-bit key), then the amount generating a collision is beyond us.

---

**Note:** There is also old [KDF1 and KDF2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/67280/18298)

$$K_i = \operatorname{KDF}(K_{master}, i) = \operatorname{H}(K_{master} \mathbin\| c)$$ where $c$ is 4 byte encoded $i$, and it was commonly used wiht MD5,SHA-1, and SHA-256.

---

A **sample** code with python [hkdf](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/67280/18298) that contains the pop count on the output's x-or;

```
from hkdf import hkdf_extract,hkdf_expand
from binascii import unhexlify,b2a_hex
import sys

def bxor(b1, b2): # use xor for bytes
    parts = []
    for b1, b2 in zip(b1, b2):
        parts.append(bytes([b1 ^ b2]))
    return b''.join(parts)

prk = hkdf_extract(unhexlify(b"8e94ef805b93e683ff18"), b"asecretpassword")
key1 = hkdf_expand(prk, b"application 1", 16)
key2 = hkdf_expand(prk, b"application 2", 16)

print (b2a_hex(key1))
print (b2a_hex(key2))

#count the number of differnt bits by x-or and popup count.
print (bin(int.from_bytes(bxor(key1,key2), byteorder=sys.byteorder))[2:].count('1'))
```

outputs

```
 b'd6208cd3e14955c6ae0dc7f5ecd38a68'
 b'3b310a2e8cc9f4854237e966d289d9ba'
 64
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I'm looking for :)