# Is there a way to generate a password from another but those 2 will have no relation?

Tags: passwords, key-generation

For example I have the password X and I want to encrypt 2 different things. Even if one of them was stolen due to a keylogger, other will be completely safe. I wonder how safe something like this would be if the master key is completely random, secure and unknown. Also with what algorithm, program would i be able to do this on Linux systems?

I think something like this is possible actually because of Electrum's key generation method. It uses one master private key to generate all the addresses and private keys.

Comment: Are you asking similar to this [Multiple AES Key Derivation from a master key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76588/18298)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple AES Key Derivation from a master key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76588/multiple-aes-key-derivation-from-a-master-key)

Answer (score 2):

Using the HKDF algorithm would work:

```
prk = HKDF-EXTRACT(salt, master_key)

Key1 = HKDF-EXPAND(prk, "info 1", digest_len)
Key2 = HKDF-EXPAND(prk, "info 2", digest_len)
```

This creates two keys that are generated from the master key, but given `Key1`, someone else wouldn't be able to generate `Key2`, as they don't know the master key.

Comment: Good idea - you can do this with the install of a library on most languages.