# Is PBKDF2 with 1 iteration acceptable for a simple random key expansion?

Tags: key-derivation, pbkdf-2, hkdf

I have a 128 bit randomly generated key. I need to expand this key to 512 bits to use with an existing encryption library that does AES-256 encryption in CBC mode with HMAC-SHA256 authentication.

The encryption library I am using also has PBKDF2-SHA512 available. Is it acceptable to use PBKDF2 with just 1 iteration to do the simple key expansion that I need? I would also need a salt, for which I suppose I could just use a hardcoded value for.

Example:

```
generated_key = crypto_safe_rand(128)
derived_key = pbkdf2(password: generated_key, salt: 'hardcoded_salt',
                     iterations: 1, algorithm: 'SHA-512')
```

My thought is that the iteration count isn't really a factor since the original "password" is randomly generated and 128 bits long.

Or would it be better to use something like HKDF?

Comment: Nope! you will still have 128-bit key material. Start with a uniform random 256-bit key

Comment: This is for [HKDF](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76588/18298) but a similar idea applies to PBKDF2.

Comment: HKDF is better suited to the purpose. HKDF allows the use of a context string (the info parameter) for domain separation between your derived AES key and the HMAC key. Since you're starting with strong randomness for the input key material HKDF-extract can be skipped, only HKDF-expand is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or would it be better to use something like HKDF?

Generally? Yes. Using HKDF is preferred, if only to communicate clearer what you're actually doing here.

> Is it acceptable to use PBKDF2 with just 1 iteration to do the simple key expansion that I need?

Yes.

To explain this, we first need to understand how PBKDF2 works. First, note that it compute $\ell$ from the input as the number of PRF (HMAC) invocations needed to get the desired key length. The key is then $T_1\|T_2\|\ldots\|T_\ell$. The $T_i$ are defined as $T_i=F(P,S,c,i)$ - with $P$ being the password, $S$ the salt and $c$ the iteration count. If we now look at $F$ we get $F(P,S,c,i)=U_1\oplus U_2\oplus\ldots\oplus U_c$ which simplifies to $U_1$ for our purposes. Finally we look at the definition of $U_1=\operatorname{PRF}(P,S\|\operatorname{INT}(i))$ - with $\operatorname{INT}(i)$ being a fixed-length 32-bit integer encoding.

Putting all of this together we see that PBKDF2 with 1 iteration yields

$$\operatorname{PRF}(P,S\|\operatorname{INT}(1))\|\operatorname{PRF}(P,S\|\operatorname{INT}(2))\|\ldots\|\operatorname{PRF}(P,S\|\operatorname{INT}(\ell))$$

which can be easily proven to be a variable output-length PRF with the same argument that is used to prove Counter-mode secure.

Finally, a variable output-length PRF keyed with a uniformly random key yields an output that is indistinguishable from a random string. The only assumption we need to make here is that HMAC-SHA512 is actually a secure fixed-length PRF but that one shouldn't worry you.

Comment: The OP's initial key is 128-bit random key. Therefore, the strength cannot be larger than 128-bit for AES-256.

Comment: @kelalaka indeed this does not give you a higher level of security it however also doesn't loose you much security