# Randomizing output of HKDF for the same input key material

Tags: keys, hmac, key-derivation, hkdf, ephemeral

Given [HKDF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869) and a master input material key $k$, I would like to derive ephemeral keys that cannot be linked together. If I understand correctly, the specification of $HKDF$ adding a unique random $salt$ while generating each new ephemeral key should randomize the output. Is it the case?

An example: I have a master input key k (unknown to the adversary). I generate 10 ephemeral keys as $x_0 = HKDF(k, salt_0), x_1 = HKDF(k, salt_1), \ldots , x_9 = HKDF(k, salt_9)$. And $x_0 \neq x_1 \neq \ldots x_9$.

Comment: See this [Multiple AES Key Derivation from a master key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76589/18298) and we can't guarantee the non-equality. Check it after generation. Also, you can extract only once, and use context info to generate multiple keys.

Comment: I mean, use extract once, and call expand 10 times with different infos

Comment: @kelalaka The link which you shared states for the HKDF extraction that "in general,  different salts with same  result in fundamentally  different PRKs." so it seems it is what I'm looking for. Why did you say that you can't guarantee non-equality?

Comment: I've added the probability calculation to the answer. Now, this may be the dupe of  [Multiple AES Key Derivation from a master key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76588/multiple-aes-key-derivation-from-a-master-key)