# How can we link AES with Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange Method

Tags: aes, public-key, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, symmetric

Actually, I am working on a project to combine symmetric and asymmetric cryptographic algorithms.

The shared secret key for AES will be generated through the Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman Key Exchange (ECDH) Method.
I have one question that ECDH will generate a shared secret key of 256 bit or more length key.
For AES-128 I need a secret key of 128 bit but ECDH is not generating the 128-bit key.

So how can I convert the variable-length key into 128 bit?

Comment: In SO, if the answer is useful, one usually upvotes, and if you are the asker, if the answer satisfies you, you can accept the answer. Have fun.

Answer (score 3):

There is already good scheme for this,  [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme (ECIES)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme#Formal_description_of_ECIES);

Once you exchanged the keys with ECDH, then you can use a KDF to derive any key length, HKDF is fine.

ECIES also authenticates the ciphertext as Encrypted-then-MAC. In order to use MAC, you need another key. You can use [HKDF to derive many keys](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76588/18298) by providing different `info` parameters for each required key. Since your key is random you don't need the `extract` part of the HKDF, if available, just use `expand` part.

As an advice, use AES-256, it is only %40 times slower than AES-128, however, it is secure against Quantum and Multi-target attacks.