# Entropy output from 256-bit Argon2 input

Tags: key-derivation, entropy, key-size, argon2

I would like to deterministically derive two different 256-bit keys from a single passphrase -- one used as an ECDSA private key, the other as a symmetric key for AES-GCM.

Would a KDF output sufficient bits of entropy, given a 256-bit input? I'm planning to use Argon2, but I'd be happy to use another KDF if necessary.

The passphrase will be generated using a [Diceware wordlist (.txt)](https://www.eff.org/files/2016/07/18/eff_large_wordlist.txt) (7776 possible words), so if I understand it correctly, a 256-bit passphrase will be $ \log _{7776}{(2^{256})} \approx 20$ words long.

Comment: KDFs don't increase the entropy, even may decrease it. Argon2 is fine with different salts or use HKDF-Expand only since you have a strong password. [Multiple AES Key Derivation from a master key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76588/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka thank you, HKDF-Expand looks perfect for my application!