# I am new KDFs. I need backgrounds of KDF and ASN x9.63, HKDF using Java

Tags: key-derivation, hkdf

JavaCard 3.1 introduces this KDF as part of this release. Can someone help me in understanding this topic clearly? (KDF ANS X9.63). I need some parameters informations. What is shared secret and shared Info, differences between them, how they are generated etc..
How to validate and corresponding code in Java ? to assert the outputs from Javacard & Java to be the same.Some unit testing to be done from my side.

Similarly the same is also requested for HKDF.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. This is a question-and-answer site. Not lecturing site. What did you read and what is not clear for you. Your question is lack of reading/search and too broad to be answered. Here [HKDF](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76588/18298), for example.

Comment: and [Formal description of KDF1 and KDF2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/67280/18298)

Comment: Another [Security of KDF1 and KDF2 (hash based KDF's)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15673/18298)