# Can deterministic wallet be seen as Key Derivation Function?

Tags: key-derivation

From [Deterministic wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Deterministic_wallet):

> A deterministic wallet is a system of deriving keys from a single starting point known as a seed.

From [KDF from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function):

> In cryptography, a key derivation function (KDF) is a cryptographic algorithm that derives one or more secret keys from a secret value such as a main key, a password, or a passphrase using a pseudorandom function (which typically uses a cryptographic hash function or block cipher)

Will I be correct to say that deterministic wallets are KDF construction, where the entity from which the secret key is derived is a seed (or word phrase)?

Comment: Bitcoin's Deterministic wallet is similar to poor's man key derivation function [KDF1 and KDF2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67280/formal-description-of-kdf1-and-kdf2). Now we have better paradigms as in HKDF; extract and expand.